# Could not parse the remainder for boolean operators in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I use a boolean operator in django template? I want to do something like:

```
{% if forloop.counter<=12 or forloop.counter>=25 %}
```

But it is giving me an error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '<=12' from 'forloop.counter<=12'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this by keeping space around `operator`

```
{% if forloop.counter <= 12 or forloop.counter >= 25 %}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#id4, i think the problem is that you forgot the space betwen the operator and the variable.
foorloop.counter <= 12

Answer (score 0):

The parser used by Django templates fails to parse the values if there is a lack of whitespace around the operators. There was a [ticket #27022](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27022) opened on Django's issue tracker but it has been marked as "wontfix" in an effort to enforce a consistent style in templates.

Hence you need to update your code and add spaces around the operators:

```
{% if forloop.counter <= 12 or forloop.counter >= 25 %}
```