# Django could not parse the remainder

Tags: python, django, web, django-templates

I looked through my code a few times and at all previous answers to this error and could still not find a solution.

Below is the code in question:

`base.html:`

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="wideth=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}Rapid Prototypes {% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/site.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
</head>
<body id="{% block body-id %}body{% endblock %}">
{% block top-nav-wrapper %}
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Rapid Prototypes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li {% if slug=='index' %}class="active"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li {% if slug=='contact' %}class="active"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="{% url 'page' 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li {% if slug=='login' %}class="active"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="{% url 'page' 'login' %}">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is said to be on the 29th line which is the line with the first if statement. The exact error statement is: Could not parse the remainder: '=='index'' from 'slug=='index''

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried putting spaces around `==`?

Comment: How did that work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not parse the remainder for boolean operators in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026571/could-not-parse-the-remainder-for-boolean-operators-in-django-template)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#operator), you need spaces around boolean operators

Comment: yes even for string comparison as well , spaces is required