# How to use If else in queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to use if else condition for Value1 in my queryset..I have found average for my records in the queryset..I need to apply condition like..If my Value1 is between 90 and 110 then I have to get message as "great" and if its below 90 it must print as "low" and if above 140 it must print as "high"

I need  to be print this output on my html file

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class graphinput(models.Model):
  user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  Month = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  Value1 = models.IntegerField()
  Value2 = models.IntegerField()
```

urls.py:

```
def average(request):   
     userid = None
     if request.user.is_authenticated:
         userid = request.user.id
         print(userid)
     dataset = graphinput.objects.filter(user=userid) \
    .values('Value1')
 
     a=dataset.aggregate(Sum('Value1'))
     b=dataset.aggregate(Avg('Value1'))
     print(a)
     print(b)
     return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
avg = b.get('Value1__avg', 0)

if avg < 90:
    message = 'low'
else if avg < 110:
    message = 'great'
else:
    message = 'high'
    

context = {'message': message}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

next access it in template with `{{ message }}`

Comment: Worked !! I was trying without getting my data so didn't achieve..May I now what is that 0 (second parameter)

Comment: If any case there is not value for Value1__avg in 'b' the default value will be 0.
It is a python dictionary feature.

Comment: I have another doubt..In my html file..If my avg is below 90 or above 110 ,I have to add a button ..If its bet 90-110 I need to display the button

Comment: Have a look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026571/greater-than-or-equal-to-forloop-counter-django-template

Comment: If am not entering anything from front end on my text box ,it throws error [Field 'Value1' expected a number but got '']..It should not thwor error even it is null

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically create a column based on the values of other columns on the fly:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

Graphinput.objects.annotate(
    message=Case(
        When(value1__lt=90, then=Value('high')),
        When(value1__lt=110, then=Value('low')),
        When(value1__gt=140, then=Value('great')),
        default=Value('not set'),
    ),
).values_list('value1', 'message')
```

more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). Also you should start class names with capital letters and variables lowercase; `Graphinput` and `value1`